# Entity Framework - Add Existing Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm trying to add a database using the Entity Data Model Wizard and keep on getting an error "An Item with the same key has already been added."

EF Designer from Database > New Connection > Error

[image: VS Error]

This is a new connection that I'm working with. Where can I view what keys are entered?

Comment: you have Table which contains the same Column twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago and found out that I have model with the same property twice. Just rename that property and it should work fine.

Comment: I've seen this problem, too!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that what you `key` in for "Save connection settings in Web.Config" is `unique`.  You can browse the `web.config` file to see what connections you've already saved.